# React - how to prevent re-render for child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I hover the number, the state `selectedItem` will change to the number hovered.

However, from what I see in Console, every time I hover a number, all 7 items re-render, which is the situation I want to avoid.

How to do it?

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(1);
  const Item = ({ itemId }) => {
    const onItemHover = (id) => {
      setSelectedItem(id);
    };
    console.log("rendering item ", itemId);
    return (
      <div
        onMouseOver={() => {
          onItemHover(itemId);
        }}
      >
        {itemId}
      </div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>Selected ITEM: {selectedItem}</div>
      <div className=".container">
        <div className="row">
          <Item itemId="1" />
          <Item itemId="2" />
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <Item itemId="3" />
          <Item itemId="4" />
          <Item itemId="5" />
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <Item itemId="6" />
          <Item itemId="7" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-panini-6gl6b?file=/src/App.js:106-118

Comment: If you make your [mcve] runnable here on-site using Stack Snippets, it makes it easy for people to demonstrate their solutions with runnable examples. Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `Item` outside the component and [`memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)-ize it:

```
const Item = React.memo({ setSelectedItem, itemId }) => {
    const onItemHover = (id) => {
        setSelectedItem(id);
    };
    console.log("rendering item ", itemId);
    return (
        <div
            onMouseOver={() => {
              onItemHover(itemId);
            }}
        >
          {itemId}
        </div>
    );
});
```

By default, `memo` will do a shallow equality check and not re-render when the properties haven't changed.

You'd pass `setSelectedItem` as well as `itemId` to it:

```
export default function App() {
    const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(1);
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div>Selected ITEM: {selectedItem}</div>
            <div className=".container">
                <div className="row">
                    <Item setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem} itemId="1" />
                    <Item setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem} itemId="2" />
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <Item setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem} itemId="3" />
                    <Item setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem} itemId="4" />
                    <Item setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem} itemId="5" />
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <Item setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem} itemId="6" />
                    <Item setSelectedItem={setSelectedItem} itemId="7" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`useState` state setters are stable, so won't cause rerendering by changing. So the `Item` will only re-render if `itemId` changes.